# (GAS) Find column, copy after and then divide by column

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I am losing my mind.
I am trying to do a (for me) rather difficult thing. I have CSV Files, that contain of Text (always in first row) and then numbers (row 2 - x).
Here's what I want to do:

1. Find Column where Row 1's value is "WORD 1"
2. Copy this found Column (lets call it CA for now)
3. Insert a new Column (CB) after the copied one and insert the copy
4. Rename Row 1 of (now new inserted) CB in "WORD 2"
5. Now Divide all Numbers in Column (CB aka the new one) through the numbers of a column where first Row is "WORD 3"

Heres what I have so far:

```
function searchString(){
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var WORD1= "WORD 1";
  var textFinder = sheet.createTextFinder(WORD1);
  var search_row = textFinder.findNext().getRow();
  sheet.getRange(1, spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().getColumn() - 1, sheet.getMaxRows(), 1).copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setValue('WORD2');
}
```

Any tips would be extremely appreciated :(

btw, noob here.

Here's what a CSV would look like non-edited:

| WORD 5 | WORD 3 | WORD 1 | WORD 8 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 6 | 7 |
| 1 | 2 | 6 | 7 |
| 1 | 2 | 6 | 7 |
| 1 | 2 | 6 | 7 |

Here's what it should look like after the script:

| WORD 5 | WORD 3 | WORD 1 | WORD 2 | WORD 8 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 6 | 3 | 7 |
| 1 | 2 | 6 | 3 | 7 |
| 1 | 2 | 6 | 3 | 7 |
| 1 | 2 | 6 | 3 | 7 |

Comment: Please paste an extract of your csv file and what you want the outcome to look like

Comment: Sorry, I did just now

Comment: so you're inserting a column basically. are the numbers always the same in every column ?

Comment: also why are you talking about csv files, when your script is trying to work with a spreadshet?

Comment: no the numbers are all different in every csv file - I am inserting a csv in another function before that from an url - that works fine - so i am basically importing a csv via url - then trying to edit it

Comment: so does your import work? do you just need to edit your spreadsheet? where do the values for the `WORD 2` column come from?

Comment: Yes, I just need the edit. The Values from Word 2 Column are "Values from Word 1 Column devided by Word 3 Column" - So i need to duplicate Column "Word 1", Rename it to "Word 2" and devide all numbers by "Values of Word 3"

Comment: What do you mean you "need the edit"? can please confirm that you need to edit the spreadsheet and that the csv files are outside the scope of the task?

Comment: yes the csv files are outside the scope of the task

Comment: OK then, with quite a bit of effort we got there. I'll work on an answer for you, but I suggest you simplify your question then for everyone else reading :)

Comment: You are right, I am trying to improve that - this is my first question on here - I am trying to simplify the question further! Thank you so much for your patience!

Answer (score 1):

Try learning JavaScript first.

Comment: I am - aditionally to this task at hand. But thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

If you run the snippet below on your sheet, it will do the job:

```js
const insertColAfter = col => {
  const { afterCol, colName } = col;
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
  const allData = ss.getDataRange().getValues();
  const headers = allData.slice(0, 1).flat();

  const index = headers.indexOf(afterCol);
  if (-1 === index) throw new Error(`Column ${afterCol} not found`);

  ss.insertColumnAfter(index + 1);
  const newCol = ss.getRange(1, index + 2, allData.length, 1);
  const previousCols = allData
    .slice(1)
    .reduce((acc, row) => [...acc, ...[[row[index - 1], row[index]]]], []);
  newCol.setValues([
    [colName],
    ...previousCols.map(row => [+row[1] / +row[0]]),
  ]);
};

const testInsert = () =>
  insertColAfter({ afterCol: 'WORD 1', colName: 'WORD 2' });
```

It's quite fast as it minimizes the number of API calls and I do as much processing as I can with JavaScript methods, rather than the Sheets API.